# подскажите регулярку PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Привет. У меня строка содержит текст "http://" или "https://". 
Мне в строке нужно проверить их наличие . Как грамотно составить выражение ? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для проверки можно использовать такую регулярку:

```
/https?:\/\//
```